# Using FSTAB to mount by Hostname

Tags: mount, fstab

I am dealing with an office where are constantly switching computers. I would like to mount some of the windows shared drives onto a Ubuntu PC but FSTAB only seems to take IP addresses.

Is there a way I can mount based on hostname? Also could I have it add and remove mounts based on the naming convention "PHOTOGRAPHER#"

Something like IF PHOTOGRAPHER# appears on network, attempt to mount.

Ideas? Regards,

Comment: I'd put names in 'hosts'; its not as automatic as DNS but allows scripting (ie. a cron job can check and update).  I've done conditions by scripting mounts (sysvinit called scripts) but have since opted to remove (if it's not up; just a slower boot due timeout on fstab mount)

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) says that you can only mount by hostname if the name appears in your `hosts` file.

Which wouldn't help you because you'd have to constantly update your `hosts` file.

Would mounting the drives through a file manager work for you? You can do that with server name.